# What's the correct flow for my program?

Tags: php, mysql

An analogy to my problem, 
So I have a table named sample_table, it has 1 field named input. The sample_table has 2 records, "A" and "B". My program can update either of the two, and there is a validation. If I change "B" to "A", it will be invalid, (A is already existing). Same on changing "A" to "B" (B is already existing). This validation works because before the update query happens, I will do a select query, checking if the value is already existing, and if no value is existing then update will happens. The problem is, if I update "B" into lowercase "b", my program validates and detect B is already existing. How can I update B to b? That is what I want to happen.

My codes

```
 <?php

function update()
{

$sup_id = $_POST['flavor_id'];
$flavor_name = $_POST['flavor_name2'];
$flavor_name = trim($flavor_name);

$sql = "update flavor set flavor_name = :flavor_name where id = :sup_id";

$stmt = "SELECT * FROM flavor WHERE flavor_name=:flavor_name";

try
{               
$STM2= $conn -> prepare($stmt);                                        
$STM2->bindparam(":flavor_name", $flavor_name);
$STM2 -> execute();
$row=$STM2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

if(strtolower($row['flavor_name'])==strtolower($flavor_name))
{
 echo " <p class=failed> Flavor is already existing </p>";
}
else
{
$STM = $conn -> prepare($sql);                                    
$STM->bindparam(":sup_id", $sup_id);
$STM->bindparam(":flavor_name", $flavor_name);
$STM -> execute();
echo " <p class=success> Flavor Updated</p> "; }
}
catch( PDOException $e )
{
echo $e->getMessage();
}
}


?>
```

Comment: Show your code.  I have an educated guess of what the problem is, but if you show your code then people can give specific advice rather than guess.

Comment: @Leon Flow Please explain if you want to keep the both values i:e uppercase 'B' and lowercase 'b' in the table?

Comment: I can update a record as long the inputted data is not existing. But what if I just want to change the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL queries are not case sensitive by default.  You can set a column to be case sensitive by manipulating its [collation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/charset-general.html) to be case sensitive or case insensitive.  But you may not wish to have case sensitivity baked into the column itself (unless you need that for indexing purposes, see below).

In order to run a case sensitive query, you need to use the `BINARY` keyword to cast your column appropriately:

```
SELECT * FROM sample_table WHERE sample_column = BINARY 'a';
```

That will only give you columns matching "a", not "A".

You would need this type of logic if you want to display some intelligent error message to the user.  If instead you just want to create an exception scenario, or ignore the change, you could instead create a [Unique Index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-index.html) on your column - for your situation you'll need to make sure that it's case sensitive.  Then you could do the following:

```
UPDATE [IGNORE] sample_table SET sample_column = 'a';
```

The `IGNORE` is optional, that's why it's in brackets. That will update the column if it does not violate the unique index, it will give you a MySQL error if it *does* violate the unique index and you omit `IGNORE`, and it will silently have no effect if it violates the unique index and you use `IGNORE`.

Edit to address the code that is now in OP's question:

So, you're specifically using `strtolower()` on your results which squashes any case differences.  You could remove those calls from your code and compare the strings directly:

```
//if(strtolower($row['flavor_name'])==strtolower($flavor_name))
if($row['flavor_name']==$flavor_name)
```

... and that would probably be what you're looking for, or you could use the query modifications above to not even receive a matching result if the case doesn't match.

Comment: Jason thank you so much! it works! Haha! you made me cry.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ASCII character code to represent the letters 'A' and 'B' and their lower case letters 'a' and 'b'. for example: to store char 'A' before putting it in database change it to ASCII code which will be 65, if you want you can change it back to character later.